# How to construct an XPath/CssSelector for the dynamic button where class, ID and name are not present

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

below is the inspected content, Kindly help me in locating the Checkout button.

```html
<button data-testid="continueCheckoutButton" ng-class="continueDellMetricsClass" ng-click="continueButtonClick()" ng-disabled="disableContinueButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block continueButton" data-metrics="" type="button">Checkout</button>
```

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm col-sm-6 top-padding-mini bottom-offset-mini">
                    <button ng-class="continueDellMetricsClass" ng-click="continueButtonClick()" ng-disabled="disableContinueButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block continueButton" data-testid="ContinueAction" data-metrics="" type="button">Submit Order</button>
                </div>

Comment: Please add your code into the question itself. It´s impossible to read within the comments. There´s an "edit"-button on your question to update its content.

Comment: Id and Name are not Present in the Inspected element , Kindly share the how to locate it /driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Checkout')]/following-sibling::button[1]")).Click();

Comment: @KeshavBabu There is no `Checkout` button as such but a _button_ with text as **Submit Order**. Are you looking for that?

Comment: @DebanjanB please find the checkout button html content since all are of same type I just mentioned it <button data-testid="continueCheckoutButton" ng-class="continueDellMetricsClass" ng-click="continueButtonClick()" ng-disabled="disableContinueButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block continueButton" data-metrics="" type="button">Checkout</button>

Comment: Whether any one of the button will be displayed at a time?

Comment: When I copied the XPath in HTML page itself and I looked into the fresh page , it is not able to find. It requires two times Inspection . if not is not able to locate that element could you please provide me the solution , how to locate when we need to inspect element twice to locate it's exact path. 
/html/body  -> When Inspect for First time I could see only this(all the content is under this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button name is getting changed dynamically, then you can use the below xpath

```
//button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass']
```

**Edit:**

First you need to perform the page scroll down action using `IJavaScriptExecutor` and then need to find the element with the reference of `cartsummary` div.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//div[@ng-class='PaymentIconsEnabledCss']//button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass']")));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@ng-class='PaymentIconsEnabledCss']//button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass']")).Click();
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? Add some explicit wait before using the xpath. Updated answer. Please try with the updated answer and then share the error details,If any

Comment: No Such element Exception encountered.

Comment: If I tried to inspect that element it won't shows ( It just shows the html/body), If repeat the inspect then it will shows the html content(where the button is defined)

Comment: Can you try to navigate using XPath in Developer Tools? Just press F12 and then Ctrl + F. Search with //button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass']. After searching, please check whether any element is getting highlighted in your application

Comment: When I  tried to navigate using XPath in Developer Tools,by pressing F12 and then Ctrl + F. Searching with //button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'] it highlights " with matching count 3. but if I tried same thing by putting in code it throw 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 
 OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()"

Comment: Yeah totally 3 elements might be matched and only one element alone may be visible in UI.This error is throwing for the non visible element. There could be two elements might be hidden. Can you share those three highlighted element HTML?

Comment: Please search and check like //button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][1], //button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][2],//button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][3] and check the element highlight in your application as well in developer tool

Comment: //button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][3] highlights in your application as well in developer tool, but in code it's not working:OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@ng-class='continueDellMetricsClass'][3]"}

Comment: Oh. whether you are using same locator as well in explicit wait condition? Whether the URL is accessible to me?

Comment: Place url "https://www.dell.com/en-us/cart?cs=19&~ck=mn" If we dont't have active cart item then search for "Laptops " in the search bar and then Add one cart item to it .Click on " Go to Cart" now it will land on cart page . Where the checkout button will be Listed under "Cart Summary". I want you to locate that Checkout button. Kindly help me in locating it.

Comment: @KeshavBabu: You cannot directly access the required button.So, you need to find the element with the reference of cartSummary section. I have updated the answer . Updated code is working fine for me.

Comment: Subburaj the code is now broken .. with the fix which you have given earlier. could you please .
Place url "dell.com/en-us/cart?cs=19&~ck=mn" If we dont't have active cart item then search for "Laptops " in the search bar and then Add one cart item to it .Click on " Go to Cart" now it will land on cart page . Where the checkout button will be Listed under "Cart Summary". I want you to locate that Checkout button. Kindly help me in locating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath:

```
//button[text()='Submit Order']
```

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Checkout']")).click();
```

Comment: You have changed your element in the question. See the updated answer. Also, as others have suggested, add some explicit wait and wait for the element to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the element is an [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

```
var myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block continueButton' and contains(.,'Checkout')]")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//contains[text(),'Submit Order']
```